# Finding $Q$ for any $A$ s.t. $QAQ^\top = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, svd, matrix-decomposition

Given an invertible and PSD matrix $A$, I am looking to find $Q$ such that: 
$$
QAQ^\top = I
$$
What is a/the right/efficient way to do this?

Here is what I did: SVD gives
$$
A \approx U S V^\top 
$$
Then to make things to the form of
$$
A \approx U \hat{S} U^\top 
$$
by $$
\hat{S} = S ( U ^{-1} V )^\top 
$$
We can rewrite : 
$$
A \approx U \hat{S} U^\top = \left( U \sqrt{\hat{S}} \right) I  \left( U \sqrt{\hat{S}} \right) ^\top   
$$
To find $Q$, set $Q =   \left( U \sqrt{\hat{S}}  \right)^{-1}$.

Is there any better/more efficient(computationally) way to do this?

---

Here is my code in MATLAB. I first find the SVD, and use an inversion to find $Q$. I wonder if there is a way to skip the inversion and find $Q$ directly.

```
AA = rand(10,1);
A = AA*AA';  % random positive definite matrix 
[U S V]=svd(A);
d=diag(U'*A*U);
S_hat=S*spdiags(sign(d.*diag(S)),0,size(U,2),size(U,2));
UU = U * (diag(diag(S_hat)))^(0.5); 

Areconstruct1 = U*S_hat*U'; 
Areconstruct2 = UU*eye(size(U,2))*UU'; 

% Check
norm(Areconstruct1-Areconstruct2)
norm(Areconstruct1-A)/norm(A)
norm(Areconstruct2-A)/norm(A)

Q = UU^(-1); 
Q*A*Q';
```

Comment: Why would there be one? $A$ need not be invertible, but if there is a $Q$ then $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Suppose $A$ is invertible. I corrected the definition.

Comment: doesn't your conclusion imply that $A$ is symmetric as well?

Comment: I guess your specification of $A$ misses an important point that $A$ is supposed to be SPD. If that is so, $A$ is orthogonally similar to a (positive definite) diagonal matrix $U^TAU=D$, so $D^{-1/2}U^TAUD^{-1/2}=I$. Set $Q:=D^{-1/2}U^T$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Ah I had this. Mistakenly removed. Added PSD to the definition.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel I literally do whatever you just suggested. But is it the best way we can do this? I want to get rid of the inversion D^-0.5

Comment: Well, inversion of a diagonal matrix is the least inefficient part of the whole process.

Comment: In addition, if $A=USV^T$ is an SVD of an SPD matrix, then $V=U$, that is, the SVD is identical to the spectral decomposition of $A$.

Comment: Since it is invertible, PSD, you can just say the matrix is positive definite (not just semi-.)